# Over signature $S= \{f \}$, $n_f=1$, find a formula $\phi$ so that for every structure, $M \vDash \phi \implies|M|$ is infinite

Tags: model-theory, first-order-logic

Over signature $S= \{f \}$, $n_f=1$, find a formula $\phi$ so that for every structure, $M \vDash \phi \implies |M|$ is infinite

I'm trying to solve this for a really long time. I tried to perhaps think of infinite orbits, however I can't see how to define this in a finite formula. Any assistance will be great!

Comment: It's better to use $\implies$, since $\rightarrow$ can be mistaken for a connective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT:** If $X$ is a finite set, then every function $f\colon X\to X$ is injective if and only if it is surjective. What sort of condition would imply that $X$ is infinite? Now use the fact that you have a function in your language to talk about.

Comment: Pretty stuck even with that hint. Demanding the function being surjective/injective, both or none doesn't (I think) guarantee the set being infinite. I'm probably just missing something. Since in a structure, the function $f$ already is given a meaning, I can't really say "for every function $f$..", or can I? We only have "one" function in a given structure.

Comment: Read the hint again, being finite implies that *every* function is  injective$\iff$surjective. What sort of condition would imply that a set is infinite? Now use the fact that you are given a function to talk about.

Comment: If $f$ is injective but not surjective?

Comment: For example, yes.

Comment: I see... it's simpler than I thought. Thanks!